# Modifying product view without modfying the phtml file?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I've yet to find a proper answer for this, therefore I decided to ask it here.

I'm new to Magento and trying to develop an extension that'll modify the product and category pages.

I want to make it work in every template, meaning I'll need to find a way to modify these pages without editing the template files.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following observer to change the content in `template(phtml)` file with edit the core template file.

> core_block_abstract_to_html_before
>
> core_block_abstract_to_html_after

refer [**this**](http://blog.belvg.com/template-override-in-magento-hidden-pitfalls-and-ways-to-avoid-them.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the given Child-Blocks within the respective view files. `/catalog/product/view.phtml` for example contains `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>`. So you could use that and add a block via your `layout.xml` and refer to that, for example:

`<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/template" name="product.info.other" as="other" template="someTemplate.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>`

You could use any of the blocks echoed in the template and just wrap it in your own template file. Of course, you wouldn´t really change the whole page really, but you could add a lot without touching any core .phtml-files.